# Sharepoint Search Box is requiring Authentication.. Help :)

Tags: search, authentication

Seems like it should be relatively easy, but I'm having difficulties allowing anonymous users to enter a value in the search box without share point prompting that user for authentication. I have allowed anonymous users to access the site and that seems to be working fine. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you also allowed anonymous access on your search center site?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like the Search Suggestions is requiring authentication. Try disabling them if you don't really need them. If you do need them, looks like you'll have to implement something yourself using a custom HTTP Handler and JavaScript, like in this blog: http://www.mavention.nl/blog/search-query-suggestions-anonymous-users-sharepoint-2013-mavention-query-suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested to check this:
http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2008/02/20/SharePoint-search-and-anonymous-users.aspx

Or on the other hand you can also create your own custom search page and redirect the users to this custom page. This will not cause the anonymous users a problem is searching content on SharePoint Site. But if you are using the default OSSSearchResults.aspx page then the above article should solve your problem.